Change Java path in Android Studio for a Flutter project
I was using Java 21 for my project, but now I want to use Java 17. So I uninstalled Java 21 and installed Java 17. After that, when I run ./gradlew signingReport in the terminal for the SHA key, it always keeps the same path, which is for Java 21. How can I change the path to Java 17? I also set up the JAVA_HOME to Java 17, but it still looks for Java 21.
~\StudioProjects\medauth\android git:[minimalistic]
./gradlew signingReport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


when you set java to 17, have you tried running java --version in terminal to see if your java version is 17 for current shell? You might want to do source <bashrc path> or restart terminal to see the effect.
